# How can a widely used custom button track which class its onclick is called from?

Tags: android, android-layout

In my application, I have a custom button that is used in many different custom views. 
The behavior differs very slightly depending on which view the button was clicked in, I want to have one @OnClick implementation in my custom button class that takes care of every case in order to avoid having similar code in every custom view class.

Is there a way I can determine in the @OnClick block where the button was clicked from?

It looks something like

```
public class customButton extends appcompactimagebutton {  
    //stuff  

    @OnClick  
    public void onbuttonclick(){  
        //handles general behavior  
        //if (clicked from customViewA) {  
            //do A stuff  
        //}
    }  
}
```

and then I have customViewA that has a customButton within it, I'm not sure what to put in the if statement, if that's even a proper way to handle something like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the tag attribute. In your XML layouts, add a line

```
android:tag="viewname"
```

to the XML for the button (in code you can do `.setTag("viewname")`. You can then just modify your onClick to check the tag using `this.getTag()` and use that to identify where the click came from.

Comment: This is exactly what I've been looking for, thank you